# AVAusioSession pty error in Simulator

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I have a simple code to a play sound through `AVAudioPlayer`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"beep"
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];

self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
self.player.volume = 1;
[self.player prepareToPlay];
```

My exception breakpoint will stop at `prepareToPlay` and console log wrote:

> ERROR:     AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:111: GetProperty:
>   AudioSessionGetProperty ('prp?') failed with error: 'pty?

After 2x tapping to pass through this breakpoint, application will not crash. This happened only in the simulator.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Following code might be helpful.

```
NSURL *url;
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/beep.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
self.audioPlayer .delegate = self;
[self.audioPlayer  prepareToPlay];
[self.audioPlayer  play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a Simulator specific error. This error doesnt come up on the device. There is a discussion here if you want to know more.
[AVSpeechSynthesizer error AudioSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935875/avspeechsynthesizer-error-audiosession)